# How to convert datetime to timestamp in MS SQL stored function

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

There is a stored function which is called from table update trigger. Smt like this:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTime2ToBigInt](@dt DATETIME2(7))
RETURNS BIGINT
```

Need to convert input datetime to unix timestamp.

Tried `CONVERT( timestamp, @dt)` and `CAST(@dt AS TIMESTAMP)` but both result in

> "Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to timestamp is not
>   allowed."

Of course it's possible to do by mathematics, but I can't believe, that mssql doesn't have direct convert function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
@ctimestamp datetime
)
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN
  /* Function body */
  declare @return integer

  SELECT @return = DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, @ctimestamp)

  return @return
END
```

**try the function :**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETDATE());
```

Comment: Seems to me you should be using GETUTCDATE() for a proper unix timestamp.  Otherwise, your unix timestamp will be based on the timezone.