# Convert self-defined/custom datetime format to datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

In PostgreSQL, I can convert datetime to timestamp like below

```
to_timestamp('2019-12-20-15-12-42','YYYY-MM-DD-hh24-mi-ss')::timestamptz
```

How do I do it in SQL Server? I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
select FORMAT(CAST('2019-12-20-15-12-42' AS datetime), N'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

This query throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: You will find the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915453/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-in-ms-sql-stored-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert datetime to timestamp in MS SQL stored function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915453/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-in-ms-sql-stored-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server have no built-in function which converts custom datetime string into DATETIME format.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(literal, 1, 10) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(literal, 12, 8), '-', ':')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=94c99fb415c3e7021888ff9949dbc97d)

You may use this expression and create your own function.